# iPhone App Database?

Tags: iphone

I've programmed in other languages and such, but I'm still a bit of an iPhone noob. My hope for my app is to store around 2,100 items or so, each having information and an image, and allow the user to select from a list of these and add them to to a TableView.

Is storing this large amount of data realistic? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing 2100 items in SQLite is possible and will work properly. The only thing to keep in mind is to always filter before showing and never display more than 100 or 200.

Answer (score 3):

You should be fine, if your images are not too big. If the average size of one image is about 100K, you'll need something in the order or 210MB, which would be fine. Not ideal, but fine.

However, if the average size is 1MB, you're looking at roughly 2GB storage. The low end iPhones have 8GB of storage. Users take considerable amount of that space for music, pictures and apps. 2GB for single app is way too much, and it's unlikely you'll be able to get that space.

Comment: If I do include the images, they'll be very, very small. I'm considering just scrapping them entirely if it will streamline the process. Thanks for the heads up, though!